# I am getting an error in Eclipse after installing Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I was following a JavaFX tutorial on YouTube and tried to run the bare bones code to make sure everything was installed correctly and got an error. This is also my first post so I am not too sure what I need to include.

Here is the code:

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class HelloWorld extends Application {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.show();
    
    
}
```

}

Here is the error:

Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/application/Application

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Answer (score 0):

Basicly java fx is not in your classpath.

I think it will be easiest if you use maven to set the dependencies. If you use maven then the dependency you need would be:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
    <version>11</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This should add all the transitive dependencies nessesary.

Comment: I couldn't figure out how maven worked so I added "package name of project;" and also a VM argument pointing to my javafx.controls. Is this a bad solution, or does this accomplish the same thing?

Comment: If you only want to test jaxafx - No. For a complete solution you would normaly build it via maven, gradle or some other build tool.